# Yoast Custom Sitemap not working in Yoast 5.0

Tags: xml, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why wordpress won't run this filter. I added it to my Active Child theme's functions.php, there is NO other code in functions.php

```
/* Add External Sitemap to Yoast Sitemap Index
 * Credit: Paul https://wordpress.org/support/users/paulmighty/
 * Last Tested: Oct 07 2016 using Yoast SEO 3.6 on WordPress 4.6.1
 */
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', 'add_sitemap_custom_items' );
function add_sitemap_custom_items(){
$sitemap_custom_items = '<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap-2.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap-3.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>';
return $sitemap_custom_items;
}
```

This was copied from here: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/add-external-sitemap-to-index/

it does not work. I'm using Yoast 5.0 and Wordpress 4.8

Answer (score 1):

Instead, Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-actions-and-filters/

Add your code just like this within the body of the plugin as explained in the image bellow:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', 'add_sitemap_custom_items' );
function add_sitemap_custom_items(){
$sitemap_custom_items = '<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap-2.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.website.com/external-sitemap-3.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>';
return $sitemap_custom_items;
}
```

[image]

This plugin injects filters in a different way that we usually do manually. Hence It should bypass any incompatibility that is deterring the filter from being executed.

Comment: You are not answering the question.

Comment: I tested it in localhost and it worked for me so I am not sure why you would vote down my answer.

Comment: because the question refers to Custom Sitemaps in Yoast SEO and this article https://kb.yoast.com/kb/add-external-sitemap-to-index/ if the plugin you suggested works, you should explain why is the example in the article not working. please edit the answer and i will vote it up

Comment: @Mauro Yes, throughout this plugin you can force custom filters of your own, and in this example, I added a filter that adds custom sitemaps within Yoast sitemap file "sitemap_index.xml"